# Related to layer 3 switch

Tags: routing, switch, vlan

I have four LAN that are separated by VLAN. Access switches are connected to a L3 Core Switch.
I have a main Server and my ISP that are connected to the L3 Core Switch.

The main server needs to communicate with all the VLAN but those VLAN need not to communicate with each other.

What is the procedure that I have to done for this criteria in L3 switch (commands)?

Comment: we cannot give you any command if we don't know what brand, model and software version are your switches.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe can be achieved by a Router with Access List. Each LAN may have it's seprate vlan (as well L3 subnet). Then put Access Rules allowing flow from server to each access LAN and denying everything else.
This seems to be simplest option for your needs as I understood it

Answer (score 1):

Private VLANs could help in such scenario . please make use of this link [this link](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst3560/software/release/12-2_52_se/configuration/guide/3560scg/swpvlan.html#wp1044399)